# connect woocommerce products to pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce on my wordpress site. I am selling artwork. The products are arts. I have a list of artists as pages. Each artist is one page. I would like to connect the pages and products so I can show the artist's name on the art page and the user can click on the name and it takes them to the artist page. How do I do this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, But I will show you a custom way to do it

1. Enable the Author meta box for WooCommerce products by adding the below code in your active theme's functions.php

   add_action('init', 'ehi_add_author_woocommerce', 999 );
   function ehi_add_author_woocommerce()
   {
   if (post_type_exists('product'))
   {
   add_post_type_support('product', 'author');
   }
   }
2. Assign authors to products (User of WordPress, WordPress by default create author page it will easy for you to use author page)
3. On the product single page add custom code to show Author information
   Code Exampl: